# Is it possible to override gemfile for local development?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, gemfile

We have a `Gemfile` currently in our git repository. However, there's a gem I use only locally in my environment (my team doesn't use it). In order to use it, I have to add it to our `Gemfile`, but every time I check out to our master/dev main branch, I have to remove it because of conflicts with the tracked gemfile.

What I would like is something like a `Gemfile.local` which would inherit the gems imported from the `Gemfile` but to also allow new gems to be imported there to use on my machine only. This file would be ignored in `.gitignore`. Is this even possible?

Comment: Does any of the solutions provided here help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962743/bundler-load-multiple-gemfiles

Comment: Will give it a try @MichaelKohl thanks :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set `BUNDLE_GEMFILE` environment variable:

```
BUNDLE_GEMFILE=Gemfile.local bundle exec rails c
```

---

To provide a “delta” only in the `Gemfile.local` put `require_relative 'Gemfile'` on top of it (or `Bundler::Dsl#eval_gemfile` as suggested by @MichaelKohl in comments.)

Comment: The question is about adding a _new_ gem, not redirecting existing one.

Comment: Yes, the second one would kinda work. Except that `Gemfile.local` would have to be a full self-sufficient gemfile (cue the problems with syncing it to the main branch). What I imagine Luis asks: is there a way to supply a local, git-ignored __delta__ to the main Gemfile? A patch, if you will.

Comment: I'm guessing one could simply `load` the main gemfile from the local one and then supply the delta.

Comment: Or use `Bundler::Dsl#eval_gemfile` for that purpose.

Comment: This worked, thanks. I've used `Bundler::Dsl#eval_gemfile` :)

Comment: When first setting this up, I would recommend copying the existing `Gemfile.lock` to `Gemfile.local.lock`, otherwise the gem versions used to create `Gemfile.local.lock` the first time you run `BUNDLE_GEMFILE=Gemfile.local bundle install` may be very different than the ones in your team's `Gemfile.lock`.

Comment: I want to clarify what I think @MichaelKohl means by 'use' `Bundler::Dsl#eval_gemfile` is to add a line like:
`eval_gemfile 'Gemfile'` within `Gemfile.local`.

Answer (score 1):

Put below code at the top of your `Gemfile.local` to load existing `gemfile`:

```
if File.exists?('Gemfile') then
  eval File.read('Gemfile')
end
```

It will load all gems from existing `Gemfile`. You can add new gems also as you need.

Run below commands to install gems from new `Gemfile.local`:

```
bundle install --gemfile=Gemfile.local
```

Comment: Even though I've accepted the answer below, this one works too. I found using `Gemfile::Dsl.new.eval_file` to be cleaner :)

Comment: Thanks, it is more cleaner.